# Allocating memory for an argument in a function using ** or *&

Tags: c++

I've seen two different solutions on how to allocate memory for an argument within a function:

**Using **:**

```
template <class T>
void funcPP(T ** ppnDynamicInt) {
    *ppnDynamicInt = new T;
}
```

vs

**Using *&**

```
template <class T>
void funcRP(T *& pnDynamicInt) {
    pnDynamicInt = new T;
}
```

Example using the functions ->

```
int * pnDynamicInt;
funcPP(&pnDynamicInt);
funcRP(pnDynamicInt);//memory leak I know ;)
```

What is considered a safer/better style? Is one solution more efficient?

(Note: I know it would be better with smart pointers :))

Comment: It would be better to return the value.

Comment: Memory leak? I don't think so.

Comment: @Jorn it's a memory leak because the previous value of `pnDynamicInt` was not deleted/freed before it was assigned a new value, and there is no way to access that pointer anymore.

Comment: @Isaac, Ah I see, didn't consider that. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I thought references were immutable; can someone explain it :) ?

Comment: @perencia the reference is not being changed; the value of the variable it references is being changed

Comment: Any problem in using the new expression directly?

Comment: @Adam, thanks I had a great misunderstanding there.

Answer (score 6):

As you are only considering between the two alternatives shown,
I'd suggest `funcRP`, since the language guarantees that `pnDynamicInt` is never null (references can't be null) but `*ppnDynamicInt = new T;` could cause undefined behaviour if `ppnDynamicInt` is a null pointer. Other than that they are identical (except that `funcRP` uses neater syntax)

Note: depending on how your using the functions, you may want to delete the previous value, such as with `delete pnDynamicInt`.

Edit: By 'guarantees' I mean there is no non-undefined way of having a null-reference, whereas null pointers are well-defined.

Comment: FYI in practice it is possible to get a null reference: `funcRP(*((T**)NULL))`. Though that is undefined behavior, it should not be tested for, and whoever does it deserves a segfault.

Comment: @Adam Maybe 'guarantees' is a poor choice of words, but in that case you are dereferencing a null pointer which is undefined, so technically anything could happen, it may not even call the function. Whereas in the case of a pointer argument, `funcPP(nullptr)` would be well defined and would call the function (of course the statement `*ppnDynamicInt = new T;` would now be undefined.)

Comment: @Adam: Your code example is no "null reference" precisely because it is already undefined behaviour. There are no null references in C++.

Comment: I agree completely. I'm just pointing out that just because it's undefined behavior doesn't mean that some poor sod won't concoct a case where it can happen. For example, they do have a `T**`, hence they dereference it to pass it to `funcRP`, and the value of that is computed in some way that can return 0. Like I said, "in practice".

Answer (score 1):

I prefer funcPP since it's more explicit on the call site that the pointer may get changed.